# Query Json Object List

Tags: c#, json

I have some json that looks like this:

```
    string jsonobj =
    "[{'LastTighteningResultDataRev3': 'DataFields', 'Attribute': ['BatchSize','107','2','109','4']},
      {'LastTighteningResultDataRev3': 'DataFields', 'Attribute': ['BatchCounter','113','2','115','4']},
      {'LastTighteningResultDataRev3': 'DataFields', 'Attribute': ['TighteningStatus','119','2','121','1']}]";
```

I have created a Json deserialized object list:

```
 var tempObj = new[] { new { LastTighteningResultDataRev3 = "", Attribute = new List<string>() } };
 var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(jsonobj, tempObj);
```

I need to query the "TighteningStatus" and retrieve the value "1".  What is the best way to accomplish this.

I came up with this.  Not very proud of it.  There has to be a better solution then this:

```
var deserializedList = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(jsonobj, tempObj).ToList();
                                deserializedList.Where(x => x.LastTighteningResultDataRev3 == "DataFields").Select(y => y.Attribute).ToList().ForEach(attrs =>
                                {
                                    int i = 0;
                                    bool sw = false;
                                    attrs.ForEach(attr =>
                                    {
                                        if (sw && i == 3)
                                        {
                                            string TightenStatusValue = attr;
                                            sw = false;
                                        }
                                        if (attr == "TighteningStatus")
                                        {
                                                sw = true;
                                        }
                                        i++;
                                    });
                                });
```

Any recommendation to improve my code would be appreciated.

Comment: Does deserializedObject[2].Attribute[3] work? Set a debug point just after the line were you deserialize it and then use your "Immediate Window" to play with the object.

Comment: When you mean retrieve the value "1", did you  mean index of TighteningStatus in that collection? what is basis to retrieve 1?

Comment: Josh,  thanks for the insight.  was over thinking it for sure. Your answer was perfect